# Как спарсить со всех страниц сайта используя python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Я не особо опытна в python, поэтому если решите помочь, прошу, подробнее =)
Проблема такая, хочу спарсить этот сайт https://www.mir-priaji.ru/ (у них каталог в открытом доступе есть, так что это не воровство)

По видеоурокам разобралась, написала парсер для одной страницы, а как автоматизировать процесс для всех страниц в пределах данного url? то есть там каталог не поддаётся алгоритмированию, все ссылки уникальны, неужели всё ручками вбивать нужно?

привожу код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time


URL = 'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/catalog/aksessuary_dlya_vyshivaniya/pyaltsy_ramki/prochie_2/207569/'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:82.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/82.0', 'accept': '*/*'}
HOST = 'https://www.mir-priaji.ru'
FILE = 'catalog.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r


def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find_all('span', class_='page-item mhide')
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[-1].get_text())
    else:
        return 1

""" def get_img(html):
    p = requests.get(img)
    out = open("/upload/resize_cache/iblock/a2f/400_400_140cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/a2fd17144bc3457aa0626e7b1a6dba79.jpeg", "wb")
    out.write(p.content)
    out.close()
 """
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='wraps hover_shine')

    catalog = []
    for item in items:
        cost = item.find('span', class_='grey size13')
        if cost:
            cost = cost.get_text()
        else:
            cost = 'Цену уточняйте' 
        catalog.append({
            'title': item.find('div', class_='preview_text dotdot').get_text(strip=True),
            'kategory': item.find('a', class_='number').get_text(strip=True),
            'kategory2': item.find('div', class_='bx-breadcrumb-item drop').get_text(strip=True),
            'cost': cost,

            'kol-vo': item.find('span', class_='value').get_text(strip=True),
        })
    return catalog


def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Название', 'Категория', 'Подкатегория','Цена', 'Изображение', 'Наличие',])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'], item['kategory'], item['kategory2'], item['cost'], item['kol-vo']])


def parse():
    """ URL = input('Введите URL: ')
    URL = URL.strip() """
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        catalog = []
        pages_count = get_pages_count(html.text)
        for page in range (1, pages_count + 1):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page} {pages_count}...')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
            catalog.extend(get_content(html.text))
            time.sleep(1)
            
        save_file(catalog, FILE)


        print(f'Получено {len(catalog)} товаров')

    else:
        print('Error')    


parse()
```

Comment: Разбейте это, пожалуйста, на два вопроса. *Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала делаешь парсер для каталога (https://www.mir-priaji.ru/catalog/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше для каждого страницы каталога делаешь парсер для определения количества страниц в данном каталоге
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом парсишь ссылки на товары и проходишь по всем этим ссылкам парсером который у тебя уже написан
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

у тебя уже есть функция get_pages count которая возвращает количество страниц, я так понял проблема в том, что ты ищешь не тот класс, по факту тебе необходимо просто получить цифру количества страниц, а потом отправить N requests запросов с params =  PAGEN_1 = номер страницы от 1 до N

Попробуй вместо pagination = soup.find_all('span', class_='page-item mhide')

pagination = soup.find_all('a', attrs = {'onclick': 'BX.ajax.insertToNode*'})

Answer (score 0):

Сделала проще, просто указала 30 ссылок, и они последовательно парсятся.

```
def parse():
for URL in [

'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/catalog/bumaga_gofrirovannaya/',
'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/catalog/ывпфывпфывпmфannaya/',
'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/catalog/bфыврфаырфыарgфofrirovannaya/',
'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/catalog/buыарфваырфварфannaya/',
'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/catalog/bumagфварфварфварфannaya/',


]:

    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
```